# Return chain of char - getgrouplist in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, char

I have problem with returned char. I know that I had to allocate memory and assign to the tab if it was a string.But it is a char. I don't know which side i should go: create double array (char * tab[numbers of char][numbers of words]) or try concatenation. Function have to return chain of characters
( for example : [user, root, sudo] ).

Here is my function:

```
char * groupsName(char *ut ){ //ut it's a user nick
struct group *gr;
int i;
struct passwd *pw;
gid_t *groups;
int ngroups=0;
char * tab= malloc ( sizeof (char) * ngroups)
        pw =getpwnam(ut);
        if(getgrouplist(ut, pw->pw_gid, groups, &ngroups)<0){
            groups=malloc(ngroups *sizeof(gid_t));
            getgrouplist(ut, pw->pw_gid, groups, &ngroups);

           for(i=0;i<ngroups;i++){
                gr=getgrgid(groups[i]);
                if(gr!= NULL)  tab[i] = gr->gr_name; 
            }
        return *tab;
        }
```

}

Comment: `int ngroups=0; char * tab= malloc ( sizeof (char) * ngroups)` does not allocate any memory. Aside the `;` is missing.

Comment: for the beginning ngroups has 0, but thanks to getgrouplist, ngroups has new value.
I noticed `;` missing , this is not a point of this post...

Comment: Yes, but you did not reallocate the memory for `tab` but go on the index it with `tab[i] = gr->gr_name;` About the `;` I described it as an "aside".

Comment: Even if `ngroups` does eventually get a non-zero value, you shouldn't be calling `malloc(0)`. Also, you don't retry the `malloc` after `ngroups` is initialized, so no memory is ever allocated for `tab`.

Comment: I forgot add that ~gr->gr_name` returns a char *.

Comment: If you posted the recommended [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this would avoid silly typo mistakes. The post begs the questions: Are there any other typos? Is this your actual code? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tab is a char array. If you want to have an array of strings (an array of char arrays), as in ["user", "root", "sudo"], you can use a

```
char **tab = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * ngroups));
```

Notice also that malloc now uses sizeof(char *) as opposed to sizeof(char).

And then later:

```
tab[i] = gr->gr_name;
```

Where I assume gr_name is a pointer to the group name and still accessible after the function.

Now I might have understood your question wrong, as it is not very clear.
Either way, if you return tab, you want to return the pointer to it and not dereference it:

```
return tab;
```

If you return `*tab`, you will return the first character to which `tab` points to.

Comment: If I `return *tab` i have the last charakter of array. If I change to `return tab ` i will have  null.

Comment: tab is a pointer to a char. *tab is the first char to which the pointer points to.
actually, *tab is exactly the same as tab[0], as the compiler always translates A[i]
into *(A+i). If tab returns null, you assigned it to null. When using malloc, you should always check if malloc worked by verifying that malloc didn't return null. 
Since you want to return a char array, you need to return the pointer to that char array.